# PlPgsql function which returns result set of database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a problem in PL/PGSQL with functions. 
Basically, I have a query:

```
SELECT nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE 
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' and nspname='1' 
ORDER BY relname;
```

This query derives database statistics of opened rows in tables. But our database has a huge amount of schemas. I have to write functions that iterate over all schemes with that query, getting the number of rows opened in tables in each scheme. I have tried to Google the problem but I couldn't find any related examples.

Comment: I can not write function in pl/pgsql using the query above which returns resut set (table).Result would contain three columns, where the first column is shcema name, second is table name and third is count of rows in each table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define return value in your function, just remember to have correct datatypes or prepare to do some typecasting.

```
create or replace function get_my_database_status() 
returns TABLE(schemaname name, relname name, reltuples real)AS
$$
BEGIN
   return Query (SELECT N.nspname AS schemaname, C.relname , C.reltuples
       FROM pg_class C
       LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
       WHERE N.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
       AND C.relkind='r' -- here maybe some filtering
       ORDER BY relname);
END
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the force, read the ... err ... manual !

- [SQL Functions Returning TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE) (applies to PL/pgSQL functions too)
- [SQL Functions Returning Sets](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) (applies to PL/pgSQL functions too)
- PL/pgSQL Control Structures: [Returning From a Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

However in this case there is no need for a fancy logic but only a single SQL query is wrapped inside a function so a plain [SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) will do.

The only extra feature used here is [Copying Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE).

```
create or replace function get_my_database_status2()
returns table(schemaname pg_namespace.nspname%type, 
              relname    pg_class.relname%type, 
              reltuples  pg_class.reltuples%type)
as $$
  SELECT N.nspname, C.relname, C.reltuples
    FROM pg_class C
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON N.oid = C.relnamespace
   WHERE N.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
     AND C.relkind = 'r' -- here maybe some filtering
   ORDER BY relname;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: why read the manual when there's such a convenient example supplied right here, and with the types hint to boot!  Thanks much.